# À quel phonème correspond la désignation « l mouillé »?

Tags: histoire, phonétique

Je lisais le livre *Méchante langue* et l'auteure donne au phonène [λ] le nom de l mouillé, mais je croyais que ce nom correspondait au phonème [j], pourtant ce n'est pas le cas dans son ouvrage (il correspond non plus au phonème [l]). Le contexte c'est le changement de prononciation des mots finissant par *il* comme *nombril, outil, coutil, baril*, qui se prononcaient avec un l mouillé [λ] qui s'était amuï durant le XVII siècle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voici un lien très bien fourni sur le sujet : http://over-and-oversetter.blogspot.fr/2013/01/lhistoire-du-oui-tres-mouille-en.html.

Il semblerait que *L mouillé* [λ] n'existe plus en français mais qu'il a existé, notamment à la fin du mot *oui*. Il est très proche du *yod* [j] qu'on trouve aujourd'hui dans *fille*, *rouille*, *œil*, etc. Tellement proche que certains grammairiens ne distinguent pas les deux sons.

> Il s'est en réalité transformé. De [ʎ], il est passé à un yod, au son [j]. En linguistique, c'est ce qu'on appelle, la yodisation de la consonne palatale. La consonne spirante latérale palatale voisée [ʎ] est devenue la consonne spirante palatale voisée [j].

Apparemment il est très difficile à prononcer pour un francophone d'aujourd'hui, mais c'est un son commun en italien, et voici comment il est censé être prononcé :

> Elle se fait par un autre mouvement de la langue, tout contraire à celui qu'elle fait lorsqu'elle veut former le son de l'L sèche: car au lieu de se redresser par le bout vers le palais, elle se recourbe vers les dents d'en bas et s'élargit par le bout et vers le milieu, comme si elle voulait former un I, qui se trouve interrompu dans sa formation par le battement de la langue vers les dents d'en bas.

Comment: Si j'ai bien compris les instructions pour réaliser le son, il ressemble beaucoup au phonème du graphème _y_ de l'espagnol masi un petit plus marqué; donc je suppose que le son de l'italien dont tu parles est celui du _gli_.

Comment: @QuiqueRuiz Je ne connais ni l'espagnol ni l'italien, mais selon la source que j'ai donnée, oui c'est bien le son *gli* : "le mot *aglio* en italien, [aʎʎo] en écriture phonétique internationale, *ail* en français, [aj] en écriture phonétique". On voit bien qu'il y a un son [ʎ] et un son [j] différenciés.

Comment: Je viens d'écouter le son donné comme exemple sur le lien que tu m'as donné, et le son est exactement ça (je croyais que le son était un peu plus marqué, mais c'est exactement ça... Il y a des gens qui le font un peu plus marqué quand même). Le premier exemple est le son du _ailla_ (un mot inventé) ou d'un _ah, ja_ en allemand, le second est celui du _allá_ (_là-bas_ en espagnol; on prononce les graphèmes _ll_ et _y_ de la même façon, du moins au Mexique). Très bon le lien.